# jQuery Mobile 1.4 header issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just upgraded my project to JQM 1.4 and it looks like the header is ignoring the data-role="none" attribute if used on an  tag in the header.  This worked in JQM 1.3.2.

Please see the jsfiddle and code below

http://jsfiddle.net/caseylmanus/VL4HX/21/

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
<div data-role="header" data-theme='b'>
    <a href="#p1" data-role="none"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Back.svg/120px-Back.svg.png" style="height:15px"/></a>
     <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
    Some content here
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position='fixed'>
     <h4>Footer</h4>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6875) in jQuery Mobile 1.4 and will be fixed on 1.4.1.

To fix this until an *official fix* is released, do the following.

On `mobileinit`, set `.keepNative` option to any custom class. i.e. `.native`. Add this class to any element you dont want jQM to enhance.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.keepNative = ".native";
  });
</script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme='b'>
  <a href="#p1" class="native">
   <img src="120px-Back.svg.png" style="height:15px"/>
  </a>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tTd79/)**